# reduce the left and right margin using .Net core

Tags: css

I have build a .Net core 2.1 Application. I would like to increase my content to the whole page. Right now it shows in the middle with probably 50 of the width of the screen. i would like to leave both side margin very less. So i can display gird with more columns.

Comment: This is a CSS question

Answer (score 0):

Update the container class to under following path `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` to

`<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>`